# Tuncate CakePHP 3.X table and reset Auto Incremented id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

In the old cakePHP 2.X I used this statement:

```
$this->Products->query('TRUNCATE TABLE products;');
```

which was the only way I could get my ids reset to 1. Now in cakephp 3.X this does not seem to truncate the table at all.

I have tried:

```
deleteAll();
```

Which works but seems to always need a condition but most importantly does not reset the ID;

```
query()->delete()->execute();
```

Deletes everything but does not reset the ids.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this in **Cakephp 3.2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include "ConnectionManager" namespace in the controller

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
```

Create connection string and execute query in your action

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute('TRUNCATE TABLE tableName');
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you can execute arbitrary queries in CakePHP3 is:

```
$connection = \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default');

$connection->execute('TRUNCATE TABLE products');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-basics